# Yakuake - remap split navigation away from Shift+Tab

Tags: yakuake

Yakuake (KDE drop-down terminal) would be a very convenient tool for me, except for a single mysterious key mapping: `Shift+Tab`

What yakuake shortcut settings says it does: Nothing

What it actually does: Switches to previous terminal split

This is unfortunate, since it drowns the mapping from my vimrc to walk backwards up the autocomplete menu.

Does anyone know of a way to remap this elusive mapping? I checked in all the other KDE shortcut settings and found nothing. After all, I have no problems in Konsole...

Steps to reproduce this mysterious behaviour:

- Open yakuake
- hit `Ctrl+(` to create a split view
- hit `Shift+Tab`

I am on yakuake 3.0.5+, and the rest of my system can be inspected [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dump-your-inxi-fxxxza-no-host-here-and-bookmark-it/8298/773?u=adigitoleo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a known bug:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421632

It should be fixed in the next KDE bugfix release (20.08).